# Amazon AWS RDS: Aurora Serverless 2 for my LAMP web application

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I recently moved from a VPS to AWS; set up EC2 and the other services and thought to move my MySQL database to Aurora Serverless.

My application runs at least 2x slower than before! Batch PHP scripts that depend on the database used to take 20 minutes to run now take 40 to 60 minutes! Not to mention the massive cost per day.

Has anyone experienced this before?
Also I keep getting the same error (there's like a million of them) in all the log files of the Aurora cluster:

```
[MY-010914] [Server] Aborted connection 83952 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'rdsadmin' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets). (sql_connect.cc:845)
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no code changes in the application?

Comment: For troubleshooting you should read this aws:post - [Resolve reading communication packets error in Amazon RDS for MySQL or Aurora MySQL-Compatible](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-communication-packet-error)

Comment: There has been no changed to the application code.
Same code file running on AWS + Aurora Serverless = average 2000 seconds
Same code file running on my old VPS with localhost mysql = average 40 seconds